# python remove leading negative sign in string

Tags: python, string, negative-number

I want to test if a string has a negative leading character, and then delete that character if `True`.

I've tried:

```
value_a = "-50.1342"
temp_a = value_a.split(".") #needed for other purposes
if temp_a[0].startswith('-'):
  del temp_a[0]

print temp_a
```

The result is an empty [].
What could be the reason...?

Comment: Can't reproduce this. I get `['1342']`

Comment: You're deleting the list, that's why it's empty. Try replacing '- 'with ''

Comment: You're deleting the whole first element of the list. I think you meant to do `del temp_a[0][0]`, but that will result in an error because strings are immutable. Change that line to `temp_a[0] = temp_a[0][1:]` instead. [More on python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation).

Comment: Is there any reason why you indented the if?

Comment: You could also do `temp_a = str(abs(float(value_a)))`

Comment: JordanCamilletti sry that's a mistake it shouldn't be.

@pault thanks this worked!

Comment: Don't be sry, correct it if it is not relevant to your question! There is an [edit] button just for that.

Answer (score 2):

You have a `list` containing 1 element, the string `"-50"`.

What you want to do is mutate that string, like this:

`temp_a[0] = temp_a[0].replace("-", '')`

Comment: This value would need to be reassigned. Strings are immutable.

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 oops

Answer (score 1):

The output is zero because when you do `del temp_a[0]` You are not deleting the negative you are deleting the -50. So once you print it It makes it zero.
This is shown in the repl.it - https://repl.it/@RithvikKasarla/VapidExternalRuntimes

To make it delete the negative try something like this.

```
value_a = "-50.1342"
temp_a = value_a.split(".") #needed for other purposes
if temp_a[0].startswith('-'):
  temp_a[0] = str(int(temp_a[0])*-1)
print temp_a
```

Doing this makes the output ["50","1342"]

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it sounds like this might be what you want.

```
value_a = "-50.1342"
temp_a = value_a.split(".") #needed for other purposes

if temp_a[0][0] == '-':
    temp_a[0] = temp_a[0][1:]

print temp_a
```

This gives me

```
['50', '1342']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
value_a = "-50.1342"
value_a=value_a.replace("-",'')
```

Which will remove it given that value_a is a number.